# Python - Ordenar valores de un diccionario según la longitud de los mismos

Tags: python, diccionarios

Estoy buscando la forma de ordenar los valores de un diccionario según la longitud de los mismos

```
diccionario = {0:['arbol', 'pelota'], 1:['moto'], 2:[], 3:['gas']}

lista = ['pelota', 'arbol', 'moto', 'gas']
```

De momento el código que pensé es este:

```
lista = []
x = 6

for clave, valores in diccionario.items():
    for valor in valores.copy():
        if len(valor) == x:
            if clave == 0:
                lista.append(valor)
                del diccionario[clave][valores.index(valor)]
            elif clave == 1:
                lista.append(valor)
                del diccionario[clave][valores.index(valor)]
            elif clave == 2:
                lista.append(valor)
                del diccionario[clave][valores.index(valor)]
            elif clave == 3:
                lista.append(valor)
                del diccionario[clave][valores.index(valor)]
    x -= 1
```

Donde x es una variable para "determinar" la longitud máxima.
Pero me devuelve lo siguiente

```
lista = ['pelota', 'gas']
```

Answer (score 3):

En Python la indentación es importante.

Tú tienes

```
        elif clave == 3:
            lista.append(valor)
            del diccionario[clave][valores.index(valor)]
x -= 1
```

Esta asignación a `x` está fuera del `for` principal; se ejecuta sólo al terminar el `for`

Lo que tú buscas es recorrer todos los valores y seleccionar todos los de largo 6 primero, luego 5, etc. Eso significa que hay que colocar un `for` más externo que itere sobre el largo:

```
diccionario = {0:['arbol', 'pelota'], 1:['moto'], 2:[], 3:['gas']}
lista = []

for x in range(6, 0, -1):
    for clave, valores in diccionario.items():
        for valor in valores.copy():
            if len(valor) == x:
               lista.append(valor)
               del diccionario[clave][valores.index(valor)]

print(lista)
```

**Adición**

Hay una manera más corta y simple de hacerlo: como no me importan las llaves, solo las cadenas simplemente recorrere sus valores y los juntare todos en una lista

```
diccionario = {0:['arbol', 'pelota'], 1:['moto'], 2:[], 3:['gas']}
lista = []

for value in diccionario.values():
    lista.extend(value)
```

Esta lista hay que ordenarla por largo, para lo cual uso el método `sort` usando como llave el largo (negativo) de la cadena.

```
lista.sort(key = lambda x : -len(x))
print(lista)
```

produce:

```
['pelota', 'arbol', 'moto', 'gas']
```

Comment: Las claves las necesito para mas tarde, es una función simplificada para presentar el problema, y siguiendo tu respuesta obtengo como resultado ['pelota'] (la lista declarada como variable debe estar vacía)

Comment: @RockieM. Si, en realidad hay un problema con el método original al momento de decrementar `x`. Ahora lo edite y está OK. Ojo: el dato de la clave esta disponible, aun cuando no va dentro de la lista.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de Candid Moe ya explicó a profundidad lo que necesitas saber con respecto a por qué tu código no funcionaba.

Sin embargo, tu situación se presta a la perfección para hacer uso de la función `chain()` del módulo `itertools`. [Esta función](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) lo que hace es generar un nuevo iterable el cual es la concatenación de los elementos de internos de otros iterables.

De esta manera, podemos resolver tu situación haciendo uso de `chain()` y la builtin function `sorted()` (con los argumentos adecuados):

```
from itertools import chain


diccionario = {0: ['arbol', 'pelota'], 1: ['moto'], 2: [], 3: ['gas']}
lista = sorted(
    chain.from_iterable(diccionario.values()),
    key=len,
    reverse=True
)
```

Lo cual conlleva a que `lista` contenga lo siguiente:

```
['pelota', 'arbol', 'moto', 'gas']
```